# Cpanel - SSL Certification not working only mobile

Tags: wordpress, ssl, mobile, cpanel

Currently, I installed my *WordPress* site on *CPanel* and build the domain ssl cerificate. The genereated domain on cpanel is checked on domain checking tool and it shows `Chain Issues Incomplete`.

I think, because of this, ssl certification not working on mobile devices. But I am new to Cpanel SSL certification, need help from you.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a file (maybe css or js) that loads only in mobile, and check if it loads through https and not http.

Answer (score 0):

-> Open an FTP session to your site.
-> Edit your wp-config.php file and add define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
-> This will force SSL for both site logins and admin access. This is the most secure option for your site.
-> Save your wp-config.php file and re-upload it to the server.

NOTE: If you are using Pretty Permalinks, you may need to update the rewrite rules & reset permalinks.

Comment: where can I find the pretty permalinks

Comment: and then I already added the force_ssl_admin, but it's same as before. on mobile devices, ssl certificate not working